# Android radio button style quiz, add value to correct/incorrect answers?

Tags: java, android, xml, button, radio-button

I'm working on a questions/answers app in android in the style of a quiz, and I haven't been able to come up with a method to properly implement a value to radio button.  The value is determined by whether the answer is correct or wrong.

I feel like there's a few ways to go about it, but I'm not sure which ones might cause issues, or are simply bad programming practices.  My issue comes from the fact that the questions and answers are randomized every time the activity is restarted.  If it wasn't random, and I knew which answer would be correct, I think it'd be easier, but I want to go with a random feature.

To help clarify, I have radio buttons in an XML:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioAnswerOne"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioAnswerTwo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioAnswerThree"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioAnswerFour"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



    </RadioGroup>
```

And I have the strings for the radio buttons in the .java file:

```
    TextView q1A1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radioAnswerOne);
    q1A1.setText("This ANSWER is " + global.getA(0, 0));

    TextView q1A2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radioAnswerTwo);
    q1A2.setText("This ANSWER is " + global.getA(0, 1));

    TextView q1A3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radioAnswerThree);
    q1A3.setText("This ANSWER is " + global.getA(0, 2));

    TextView q1A4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radioAnswerFour);
    q1A4.setText("This ANSWER is " + global.getA(0, 3));
```

The strings are pulled from a class.  Each question has a class.  That class has a question string, and an array of 4 answer classes. The answer class has a string and a status (true/correct or false/incorrect).  I'm looking to implement the status portion now into the radio buttons to determine which one is correct so that if the user selects that radio button and clicks a button (to go to the next question), then the grade is calculated/adjusted accordingly.

I'm curious in how to do this. Seeing as the questions and answers are randomized everytime, I'll need to implement a function to get the status of each question and place that status as some sort of variable attached to the button.  And whichever button is selected, that variable gets pulled and is added to an integer of "questions answered correctly" and the app continues.  But I'm not sure of the java implementation to do such a thing.  Should my radio buttons be in the Java file instead of XML to work best?  Don't know the truly best way to do it (if there is one).

Comment: Even though I don't agree, # of clicks to task completion should be kept minimal to enhance UX. Keeping that in mind, using a RadioButton isn't the best way. Use Button instead and send the users to the next Q if they answer the Q correctly.

Comment: I am open for a discussion. So, you can go ahead and argue. :)

Comment: Well, I definitely welcome all points of view.  And yours is something I'll have to think a bit about.  The simpler the UI (ie. less clicks), usually the better the UX.  Though, I see it like this:  Whether the user gets it right or wrong, there needs to be a bit of feedback before the next question appears.  Especially with touchscreens, it's easy to tap somewhere by accident.  So upon tapping an answer, it should be obvious which selection was made (whether it's highlighted or outlined) as well as a "Correct!/Incorrect!" indicator before moving on to the next question.  No?

Comment: While I partially agree with you.  I just think it'd be more frustrating to cut to the next question as soon as the screen is tapped, especially for a quiz-style app.

Comment: You are assuming that all (or most) of your users will be drunkards, epileptic etc. That's not the case. Design your app for smart people. In fact, your app should make people _feel_  smart. How is it a quiz if you don't penalize users for being 'stupid'.

Comment: Let's say your app _does_ penalize people for picking the wrong option (say they get 4 points for picking the right answer in the first attempt, 3 in second and so on). In that case, we can talk about your approach. As you said, each question is an instance of a (Question) class. And this will be holding 4 Answer class instances. Keep `true/false` as a member variable for the Answer classes and assert that only one of the Answer class instances holds the `true` value. that should work fine.

Comment: Right, well I plan/hope to use some variation of that.  But, back to my main question: How do I implement that type of method into my radio buttons?

Comment: And no, I'm not assuming anything about the users.  What I mean to say is that feedback for the user is something I feel I want to maintain in my app.  I envision clicking an answer, that answer is then highlighted somehow as correct or incorrect (if incorrect, then the correct answer should be highlighted), so that I, as the user, can see if I was right.  If I wasn't right, I would like to read the correct answer to see if I can understand why it's correct (these aren't math problems, so reading the right answer should spark an "OH YEAH! That makes sense!"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70938/discussion-between-lilgodwin-and-athena).